# Game helper app misconfigured error google play services

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am getting this logcat error when I try to sign in to my app using the google+ sign in button.

```
02-08 15:58:18.566: E/SignInIntentService(836): Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.
02-08 15:58:18.566: E/SignInIntentService(836): dez
02-08 15:58:18.566: E/SignInIntentService(836):     at daj.a(SourceFile:152)
02-08 15:58:18.566: E/SignInIntentService(836):     at cnh.a(SourceFile:250)
02-08 15:58:18.566: E/SignInIntentService(836):     at cnh.a(SourceFile:231)
02-08 15:58:18.566: E/SignInIntentService(836):     at cmm.a(SourceFile:568)
02-08 15:58:18.566: E/SignInIntentService(836):     at dfo.a(SourceFile:213)
02-08 15:58:18.566: E/SignInIntentService(836):     at com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesSignInIntentService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:336)
02-08 15:58:18.566: E/SignInIntentService(836):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
02-08 15:58:18.566: E/SignInIntentService(836):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-08 15:58:18.566: E/SignInIntentService(836):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-08 15:58:18.566: E/SignInIntentService(836):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
02-08 15:58:18.574: E/LoadSelfFragment(1922): Unable to sign in - application does not have a registered client ID
```

There are two weird things about this error message.

1. It happened spontaneously, I was using my app normally and the sign in was working fine.
2. Most importantly, my app is turnbased multiplayer, so I am using a real life device and a genymotion emulator to test it. The sign in is **NOT** working on the genymotion emulator but it **IS** working on the real life device. (And the devices both have the same **.apk** installed on them)

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I was just having this same problem and I was able to resolve it by going into the Apps portion of Settings and Force Stopping Google Play Services and then clearing its cache.